# How to prove a subset of L(V,W) is a subspace- how to prove not empty

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Does the set have to contain the zero transformation i.e. $T$ such that $T(v)=0$ for all $v \in V$ to be non empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a general nonempty subset doesn't have to contain the zero transformation.

But as I understand, you ask specifically about subspaces. If a subset is a subspace it indeed must contain the zero element. In general, to show a subset $U$ is a subspace you need to show the following:

$1$. $U$ is nonempty.

$2$. $U$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

From these two conditions it automatically follows that the zero element is in $U$. So to prove the first condition you can show it is nonempty in any way, just show it contains any element. It's just that most of the time the easiest way is to show that specifically the zero element is in $U$. (but it isn't a must)

Comment: This explains my question perfectly- thank you so much!

Comment: For vector spaces with vector elements rather than transformations as elements, in class we have been taking that if the subspace doesn’t contain the 0 vector then it is not a subspace- is this technically wrong?

Comment: Also, this sounds very silly, but is the ‘zero element’ when considering transformations just The zero transformation?

Comment: @Marina Calder This is correct. As I said, a subspace must contain the zero vector, this follows from the two conditions which I wrote in my answer. So if a subset does not contain the zero vector then it indeed can't be a subspace. This is a possible way to prove a subset is NOT a subspace. (but again, it doesn't work in the opposite direction. If a subset does contain the zero vector it still doesn't mean it is a subspace. This only means it satisfies the first of the two required conditions). And yes, in $L(V,W)$ the zero element is the zero transformation.

Comment: Ok, this has cleared up a lot of things I was scared to ask. I should have asked sooner to have saved all my confusion further down the line!  Honestly cannot thank you enough.

Answer (score 0):

If $L(V,W)$ is the set of all linear mappings $T:V \to W$, then the zero transformation is linear (check this !), hence the zero transformation is in $L(V,W)$.